# Placing a rectangle in the middle of the screen (XNA sprite)

Tags: c#, xna

So I'm trying to make a little game just for fun, but I went into a wall pretty quickly. I want the "player"(Gray box), to start in the very center of the screen. However, with my current code, it centers from the box cornor instead of its center. What would I have to change, before it will center from the boxes center?

```
        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            Viewport viewport = GraphicsDevice.Viewport;
            Vector2 viewportmid = new Vector2(viewport.Width / 2, viewport.Height / 2);
            Vector2     origin = new Vector2(Player.Width / 2, Player.Height / 2);
            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Player, viewportmid, Color.White, origin);
            spriteBatch.End();

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance! =) New to the website, so not able to post images directly. Heres a link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYsn5.jpg

Comment: you'll need to offset viewportmid by half the size of your sprite

Comment: Worked smoothly. Tried tons of other stuff from the internet and that simple answer did it all. Thank you! :)